# CDF from PDF when $P(X \ \text{is} \ \text{even}\mid X\geq4)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Given a PMF p by

```
x     2    3    4    5    6
p(x)  0.1  0.2  0.2  0.3  0.2
```

And let X be a random variables with values in the set {2,3,4,5,6}

Is it correct to assume that the CDF is

$$F(x) = \begin{cases} 0.1 & \text{when} \ x=2 \\ 0.2 & \text{when} \ x=3,4,6 \\ 0.3 & \text{when} \ x=5 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

since the CDF doesn't seem to be increasing? $5\leq6$ but $f(5)\nleq f(6)$?

---

EDIT: Solved, forgot the P(X=5) in the fraction, thanks!

And what is wrong when I try to calculate

$P(X \ \text{is} \ \text{even}\mid X\geq4)=\frac{P(X \ \text{is} \ \text{even}\ \cap \ X\geq4)}{P(X\geq4)}=\frac{P(X=4)+P(X=6)}{P(X=4)+P(X=6)}=1?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$...=\frac{P(X=4)+P(X=6)}{P(X=4)+\color{red}{P(X=5)}+P(X=6)}\approx 0.57$$

Answer (score 1):

For the cumulative distribution function you should add up the probabilities, i.e., $P(X\le x) = \sum_{x_i\le x}P(X=x_i) = F_X(x)$ and note that $F_X(x)$ is non decreasing, right continuous and $\lim_{x\to \infty}F_X(x) = 1$ and $\lim_{x\to -\infty}F_X(x) = 0$.

So,  $F_X(x) = 0$  for $x<2$, $F_X(x)=0.1$ for $ 2 \le x < 3$,

$F_X(x) = 0.2+0.1=0.3$ for $3\le x <4$, etc., such that $F_X(x)=1$ for $x\ge 6$.

Comment: What you wrote is not a CDF, it is just the original pmf in a more compact form.